# Is it possible to determine the type of png compression on Android bitmaps?

Tags: java, android, png, android-framework

I know there are different types of png compression formats (using color palette for example). Is it possible to (programatically) determine the type I want to use when compressing a Bitmap in Android?

If the answer is no, can anyone suggest a method for doing so?
Thanks

Comment: determined based on what exactly?..

Comment: In my case, I would rather it be based on the number of colors in a bitmap.  I am using bitmaps that do not contain may colors, so I'd like to use this to my benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android there's no client API to specify that, because `Bitmap.compress()` calls a [native method](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/graphics/Bitmap.java#Bitmap.compress%28android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,int,java.io.OutputStream%29) which doesn't accept such a parameter.

However you can use [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html) (which BTW is what I think Android uses in its native implementation) and it certainly allows the [fine-grained control](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng-1.2.5-manual.html) you need.

But I really don't think that saving a bunch of KBytes in a GB-sized drive is worth this effort.

Comment: In my app, I am not saving the png on my device. I am sending it to another device. Since there are many bitmaps involved, I need a better way to compress them

Comment: I tried looking for ways to access libpng methods from the java code. I haven't come up with anything. Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: Look for [NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) or the PNGJ project leonbloy mentioned in his answer (didn't know of it and never used by myself)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [PNGJ](https://code.google.com/p/pngj/), it allows full control over the writing parameters.

Comment: my only problem is I can't use an Android Bitmap object and compress it via PNGJ. I have to compress the image using Android methods and then read it and rewrite it using PNGJ. Is there any way to do this without creating two files? I need this whole process to be done fast.  (BTW I understand that you are the coder of PNGJ and I wanted to say thanks for this great tool)

Comment: You should be able to encode directly from Bitmap object to PNG file by using PNGJ, by calling Bitmap.getPixels() one each row. The only thing you must do yourself is the unpacking convertion from ARGB (as Bitmap uses) to a sample per int (as PNGJ uses). I've not tried it, but it should be straightforward (I could add that as an utility method in ImageLineHelper).

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I had to make changes to the Android's skia library, since I didn't want to add any Java code (I need to make png compressions fast).
If anyone needs such a solution,
I uploaded mine to:
https://github.com/androidcompile/Android_external_skia_pngCompression